# Img overlaps div with negative margin

Tags: html, css

Given my code below:

```css
img
{
  width:400px;
}

div {
  border:2px solid blue;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  margin-top:-70px;
  z-index:999999999;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.gyazo.com/ee6bb88b3da7ce038475b8ce27fb5fbb.jpg" />

<div>
</div>
```

Logically speaking, the `<div>` is created after the `<img>`, so `<div>` should overlap the `<img>` element when I give it a negative `margin`. But why is the `<img>` element covering the `<div>` instead, and even with `z-index` applied to the `<div>`, it doesn't work?

Comment: You didn't set position on the DIV. Set a position `position: relative;` on the div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSS property `z-index` only works in the element whose `position` property has been set to a different value other than the default value.

So in a default element `<div>`, the position property is by default set to `static`. So in order to control the vertical stacking (`z-index`) relative to other components you first need to set the position, e.g. `position: relative;`.

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Here's your example:

```css
img
{
  width:400px;
}

div {
  border:2px solid blue;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  margin-top:-70px;
  z-index:999999999;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.gyazo.com/ee6bb88b3da7ce038475b8ce27fb5fbb.jpg" />
<div>
</div>
```